# Carla simulator and gpu

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to buy a HP laptop with iris intel graphic card to run the Carla self driving simulator. Can carls run on iris or I need to buy a laptop with nividia gpu. Thx u

Answer (score 2):

While [Carla was developed by Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/artificial-intelligence/researches/carla-open-urban-driving-simulator.html) their [GitHub recommends](https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla) a powerful [Nvidia GPU](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start_quickstart/).

Comparing a mid-level [NVidia GPU vs an Intel IRIS](https://laptopmedia.com/comparisons/nvidia-geforce-mx250-vs-intel-iris-plus-g7-the-nvidia-gpu-offers-better-performance-at-lower-cost/) the NVidia comes out ahead. You *could* use an Intel IRIS, but the performance wouldn't be very satisfactory.

An [Intel Arc A730M-Powered Laptop](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-arc-a730m-powered-laptop-surfaces-with-dollar1200-price-tag) would be a minimum laptop configuration, with an Intel GPU, for running Carla; still not anywhere as well as a top of the line GPU (which is necessary for AI), but I understand that cost is also a consideration for many people.

Answer (score -1):

All Deep Learning tasks generally require a NVIDIA GPU, and it is generally recommended to use them. It is given on carla website that a Nvidia GPU is recommended. Currently, Intel or other GPUs are not much compatible with tensor cores or deep learning due to lack of some structure.
Hence, a Nvidia GPU is recommended.
However, you can also use online GPUs which can provide you a better and configurable experience.